# Using group() in Magento EE with SOLR breaks pagination in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, collection-filtering, solr, enterprise-1.14

When using GROUP BY (MySQL statement) on collections in Magento CE, we need to apply something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485455/using-group-breaks-getselectcountsql-in-magento so we can get GROUP BY working fine.

I'm wondering has anyone resolve similar issue in Magento EE when using SOLR search. Listing / Search show proper number of results in all pages but pages has different #of results. Also getSelectCountSql returns wrong # of results.

Thanks